# Make screenreader say button alt-attribute instead of innerText

Tags: accessibility, screen-readers

Is it possible to force a screen-reader to read the alt-attribute instead of the text inside a button?

Example html: `<button alt="user menu">DrKawashima</button>`

When testing this with the built-in accessibility screen-reader in MacOS, I found that it only said "DrKawashima", and the alt-attribute was never used.

Is there a way to hint to screen-readers that I would rather have it say "user menu"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible - but beware of completely overriding the visible text of a button.

tl;dr - I recommend approach 4 here.

Your question addresses screen readers, but there are other types of assistive technology to consider.  In particular, sighted people using speech control (e.g. Dragon Naturally Speaking). Take care to address [WCAG Success Criterion 2.5.3: Label in Name](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/label-in-name.html).

Assistive technology deals with the [computed accessible name](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/) of an element:

- Screen readers will read the computed accessible name. Remember that the basic purpose of of a screen reader is to *read what's on the screen* - beware of trying to present a different interface to screen reader users.

  - Confusion can arise when a blind screen reader user and a sighted  person are both talking about the same screen.  For example, a telephone tech support person might say "Click on the button which says DrKawashima".  But if this is overridden, the screen reader says the button is called "User menu", and the user can't find the button they're being told to press.
  - Sighted people also use screen readers.  For example, someone with dyslexia may like to have stuff read out to make life easier.  When the computed accessible name  differs from the visible text, the screen reader is effectively lying to the user about what it says on the screen.
- Speech control will try to match what a user says, to the computed accessible name.  If a button has visible text, it's important that this text appears inside the computed accessible name of the element.  The expectation is that a speech control user can activate a button by saying the visible text.  In your example, saying "Click DrKawashima" should activate the button.  This won't work if the computed accessible name is "User menu".

  - There's a work-around for this.  Dragon Naturally Speaking has a tool to highlight all buttons using numbers:  say *"Click button"*, look for the number, then say *"Choose 2"*.  However this is a multi-step process, requiring extra effort from the user.

Note that the computed accessible name and the visible text do not have to match exactly.  Rather, the visible text must form *part* of the accessible name.

Let's look at some examples:

1. Your example with an alt attribute on the button simply won't work, because buttons don't have an alt attribute.  This isn't valid HTML:
   `<button alt="user menu">DrKawashima</button>`.

   - The visible text is "DrKawashima"
   - The computed accessible name is "DrKawashima".  The `alt` attribute had no effect.
   - This passes WCAG "Label in name", because the visible text and the computed accessible name are exactly the same.
   - However it doesn't manage to inform a screen reader user about the purpose of the button; sighted users can probably infer this from an accompanying icon or avatar image.
2. The `aria-label` attribute can be used to completely over-ride the button content: `<button aria-label="user menu">DrKawashima</button>`.

   - The visible text is "DrKawashima".
   - The computed accessible name is "User menu".  The `aria-label` attribute completely overrides the button content.
   - This approach FAILS WCAG "Label in name", because the visible text doesn't form part of the accessible name. A speech control user can't activate the button by saying "Click DrKawashima".
3. The `aria-label` attribute can be used to completely over-ride the button content, whilst duplicating the visible text: `<button aria-label="DrKawashima, User menu">DrKawashima</button>`.

   - The visible text is "DrKawashima".
   - The computed accessible name is "DrKawashima, User menu".  The `aria-label` attribute completely overrides the button content, but it duplicates the visible text.
   - This passes WCAG "Label in name".  The button can be activated saying *"Click DrKawashima"* because the visible text is inside the computed accessible name.
   - This approach is simple, but may be fragile because you have to manage two strings.
4. Include some visually-hidden text, to give screen reader users some additional context.  For example, using HTML5Boilerplate's `.visuallyhidden` class, or Bootstrap's `.sr-only` class:
   `<button>DrKawashima<span class="visuallyhidden">, User menu</span></button>`

   - The visible text is "DrKawashima"
   - The computed accessible name is "DrKawashima, User menu".  This results from the button content.
   - This passes WCAG "Label in name".  The button can be activated saying *"Click DrKawashima"* because the visible text is inside the computed accessible name.
   - This is the simplest solution, very robust.
5. The `aria-labelledby` attribute can build an accessible name, by referencing 2 element IDs:
   `<button aria-labelledby="user-menu-visible-label user-menu-suffix"><span id="user-menu-visible-label">DrKawashima</span><span id="user-menu-suffix" class="visuallyhidden">, User menu</span></button>`

   - The visible text is "DrKawashima"
   - The computed accessible name is "DrKawashima, User menu". This results from concatenating the two elements refernced by `aria-labelledby`.
   - This passes WCAG "Label in name".  The button can be activated saying *"Click DrKawashima"* because the visible text is inside the computed accessible name.
   - This is robust, but a bit more work to implement because you need to manage the ID references.

Comment: I'm very thankful for this perfect answer. Before reading this, I had implemented option 2. But I had no idea about the "label in name" standard. Now I'll be going with option 4.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to use a styled `<span>` tag inside the `<button>` with `aria-hidden`

```html
<button aria-label="screen reader text">
  <span aria-hidden="true">Visual Text</span>
</button>
```

Edit: As discussed in comment this isn't the best approach. 
As a speech control user can't activate this button.

andrewmacpherson's answer provides a more inclusive solution to this.

Comment: This approach fails [WCAG Success Criterion 2.5.3: Label in Name](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/label-in-name.html).  A speech control user can't activate this button by saying *"Click Visual Text"*.  The visible text doesn't form part of the computed accessible name, because the `aria-label` completely overrides the button content.

Comment: The use of `aria-hidden` here is a red herring.  The computed accessible name of the button is "screen reader text", regardless of whether the `aria-hidden` attribute is present on the nested span.

Comment: You're right, I didn't consider that scenario. andrewmacpherson 's answer gives much better approach.

Answer (score 2):

'alt' is not an allowed attribute within a button element. The alt attribute works with area, img and input type="image". Check out more on the topic https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#translatable-attributes and https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#global-attributes-2

Comment: This explains why the questioner's approach doesn't work, but it doesn't answer the question of whether it's possible.