# Paypal button label insertion interrupts screen reader

Tags: google-chrome, paypal, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

I have a "PayPal express checkout" button with a "Checkout" label which gets appended to the button after the page is loaded.

[image: Paypal Button]

[image: Paypal Button]

[image: Paypal Button]

When the page starts loading, the screen reader (Chromevox in my case) starts reading the title of the page and then comes down to heading and to the Alert Box, if any. This flow gets interrupted in the middle when PayPal button calls for its label and the "Checkout" text gets rendered.

I've tried adding the `aria-live="off"` property to the parent of the PayPal button, but it didn't help. Any other way to prevent it from interrupting the screen reader?

You can check the same using ChromeVox on the PayPal Button example page - https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client
The Screenreader would start reading the title but a long bell sound would interrupt it with the PayPal animation.

Comment: Where is your code

Comment: Added a link to the PayPal button where the issue gets replicated.

Comment: Can you tell me if any of this is related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223952/accessibility-sr-only-or-aria-label and https://stackoverflow.com/a/51801205/3825777 If so, can you take whatever code you can use there and edit your question to show more of an attempt to code. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65930949/edit  I don't know why you linked to the same button that you posted here on stack.

Comment: @VibhorDube https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client does not replicate the issue without your code.

Comment: @PrestonPHX, please open the URL with ChromeVOX enabled and see if it gets interrupted with a bell sound